# Insert new element without specify index

Tags: json, sqlite

I wonder if it's possible to insert(or more append) new element with some function in SQLite to Json array?

I used this function: **json_insert()** but I have to specify index

Comment: And you don't know the length of the array?

Comment: Yes, i don't know

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jarraylen).